# Fetch data from coredata in swift 3

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

When i'm going fetch data from coredata than in result `[<Swift3.Login: 0x6080002a38a0> (entity: Login; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://9AF74A1C-CF0C-4864-8402-08D3C5BFAED0/Login/p1> ; data: <fault>)]`

```
 var request: NSFetchRequest<Login>
    request = Login.fetchRequest()
    request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Login")

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        print("Results : \(results)")
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }
```

how to get data from coredata, can any one help me?

Comment: in entity only one data

Comment: Join your 3 request lines : `let request = NSFetchRequest<Login>(entityName: "Login")`

Comment: @vadian, same problem

Comment: It's more a suggestion to shorten the code rather than a solution.